# Run another Nested Text Template Files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4

In short, I need to run a text template file in another text template file.

**Details:**
My Question is we have some bunch of .tt files and they basically combine several SQL files in one place. However, they are in a hyhreacy.

1. Schema.tt
2. InitialProductionData.tt
3. TestData.tt

Basically, TestData.tt also contains all the .sql files generated by the other two along with some several other SQL files. InitialProduction.tt also contains the result SQL file of Schema.tt.

Each file is being used in different places so on.

The inside of the files look like this:

```
<#@ output extension=".sql" #>
<#@ include file="../Schema/InitialProductionData.sql" #>
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
use [SomeDatabase]
GO
<#@ include file="HelloWorld.sql" #>
<#@ include file="GoogleData.sql" #>
<#@ include file="YahooData.sql" #>
```

But in order to run TestData.tt file correctly, I need to run other .tt files first. Why I need is that when I run TestData.tt, it automatically runs other ones in order and uses the resulted scripts to generate the final SQL script which contains everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two options: Use inlcudes instead of .tt's or write your generated code to SQL files from one template.

For the first approach, all you'd have to do is  change the extensions on your .tt files to something like .ttinc and make sure they aren't set to auto generate. That way they only be run when included from another text template.

Then, you can include them like this:

<#@ include file="TestData.ttinclude" #>

Another option would be to write out the generated code to separate files from one master template.  Oleg Sych has written about this on his [blog](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/03/how-to-generate-multiple-outputs-from-single-t4-template/).

Comment: I need to run them separately also. With your way, I need to create two versions of the each file, one with .tt and one with .ttinclude, am I right?

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure about your scenario.  You may need one .TT for the tests and another .TT for the output. You'd be duplicating generated code, but I'd personally prefer that route to writing out the files "manually".  In short, Oleg's method for this is basically to store the results of the generated template into memory, then write it out to a file.

Comment: Here's the link: http://www.olegsych.com/2008/03/how-to-generate-multiple-outputs-from-single-t4-template/